# How to retrieve data from a queryset in Django and put it inside an array without putting the column name?

Tags: python, django

I have to insert the data from a query set in Django to an array (and not a dictionary) without entering the column name.

models.py:

```
class Permission(models.Model):
    perm_id = models.CharField( max_length=1, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    perm_label = models.CharField( max_length=30)
    perm_users = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py:

```
permissions = Permission.objects.all().order_by('perm_label')
array = []
name1 = []
    for type in permissions:
        name1.append(type)
        array.append(name1)
        name1 = []
```

Here I can do for example name1.append(type.personName) but I would like to loop through the data without setting the name of the column.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post your Permission model.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell what you want the final result to look like, but the likely best solution is to use a list comprehension:

```
name1 = [p for p in Permission.objects.all().order_by('perm_label')]
```

In the above, p will just return whatever you've defined in the `def __unicode__(self):` or `def __str__(self):` for your model.  If you want a specific field on the `Permission` object (for instance `perm_label`), you would do:

```
name1 = [p.perm_label for p in Permission.objects.all().order_by('perm_label')]
```

Comment: sorry but i want to loop through each row and set array = [  [0,1,2] , [1,2,3]] and each  array is a row in the table

Comment: It would definitely help to see your Permission model.

Comment: class Permission(models.Model):
    perm_id = models.CharField( max_length=1, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    perm_label = models.CharField( max_length=30)
    perm_users = models.IntegerField(default=0)

Comment: I don't want tp access them by their name ex: type.perm_id i would like to loop and append them into an array

Comment: A couple of things:  Your definition of perm_id isn't necessary - the default primary key is called "pk".  Is the field perm_users supposed to be a collection of users with a particular Permission?  If so, then you would probably want to make that a ManyToManyField relationship to the User model rather than declaring it as an IntegerField.